# How is the following a pure function?

Tags: javascript, computer-science

It states [here](https://gist.github.com/rrag/7a97c7dda1e986980293) that the following is a pure function:

```
function insert(DB, user) {
    return function() {
        throwIfUserExists(DB, user);
        var savedUser = saveUser(DB, user);
        return savedUser;
    }
}
```

and that the following is an impure function:

```
function insert(user) {
    if (DB.exists(user.id)) {
        throw Error("users exists");
    }
    var id = DB.insert(user);
    user.id = id;
    return user;
}
```

I don't understand how the first function is pure, since it returns a function that produces side effects. Am I wrong and if not, how could the function be written to be pure?

Comment: Suppose I call the first function. Do any side effects actually happen?

Comment: In the first function, you are just returning a function, you aren't executing it. So, no side effect.

Comment: `a function that produces side effects` - what side effects?

Comment: throwing an error/updating the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure function is a function which:

- Given the same input, will always return the same output.
- Produces no side effects.

Now pay attention to the first point. 
In your first example, as long as you keep sending in the same `DB` and `user` the output would be the same. The construction of `savedUser` or `throwIfUserExists` functions would affect the output of the first `insert` fn but the insert function in essence would be a pure function.

However, in the second function the output would be different for each call even though the `user` is the same. To be precise, the line `user.id = id;` is the one that is producing the "side effects".

Read Eric Elliot's article on pure functions : https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976